# Como condiciono si un EditText esta vacio o no dentro de un Intent.EXTRA_TEXT en Android?

Tags: java, android

Tengo una función que envía un email, los datos que van dentro del correo son cargados por el usuario en la app, son una serie de campos de `EditText`, ahora lo que necesito hacer es dentro de este `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` condicionar que si un campo esta vacío al momento de enviar el email, en ese campo no vaya nada, en cambio si el usuario cargo algún valor, que vaya ese valor; lo tengo de esta manera ahora mismo

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Relevamiento");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,

            Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
                    .append("<p><b>Fecha:</b>" + fecha.getText() + "</p>")
                    .append("<p><b>Obra:</b>" + obra.getText() + "</p>")
                    .append("<p><b>Ancho:</b>" + ancho2.getText() + "</p>")
                    .append("<p><bold>Observacion:</bold>" + obs2.getText() + "</p>")
                    .toString()


            )
```

Lo que quiero hacer en sintesis es; si el EditText esta vacio, el .append sea simplemente `("");` si es que no esta vacio, el .append sea

```
 ("<p>Titulo del campo:" + editText.getText + "</p>").
```

¿Alguna idea? Dentro de el EXTRA_TEXT no me deja realizar una condición `if`, probé creando una función aparte que haga la validación, pero me da error si lo tengo de esta manera:

```
  (Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ValidacionCampos()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede realizar de esta forma:

```
if(!fecha.getText().toString().trim().equals(""){

     //Agrega texto si el contenido no es "".

}else{

     //No agrega texto si el contenido es "".
}
```

aplicando lo anterior se puede realizar usando una operación ternaria:

```
.append(!fecha.getText().toString().trim().equals("") ? "<p><b>Fecha:</b>" + fecha.getText() + "</p>" : "")
```

Este sería el código completo:

```
Html.fromHtml(
                new StringBuilder()
                    .append(!fecha.getText().toString().trim().equals("")?"<p><b>Fecha:</b>" + fecha.getText() + "</p>" : "")
                    .append(!obra.getText().toString().trim().equals("")?"<p><b>Obra:</b>" + obra.getText() + "</p>" : "")
                    .append(!ancho2.getText().toString().trim().equals("")?"<p><b>Ancho:</b>" + ancho2.getText() + "</p>" : "")
                    .append(!obs2.getText().toString().trim().equals("")?"<p><bold>Observacion:</bold>" + obs2.getText() + "</p>" : "")
                    .toString()
};
```

Comment: Gracias! Funciono de esa manera

Comment: Excelente @HarlesPereira Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario que escribas todo en una sola sentencia:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
        Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
                .append("<p><b>Fecha:</b>" + fecha.getText() + "</p>")
                .append("<p><b>Obra:</b>" + obra.getText() + "</p>")
                .append("<p><b>Ancho:</b>" + ancho2.getText() + "</p>")
                .append("<p><bold>Observacion:</bold>" + obs2.getText() + "</p>")
                .toString()
        ));
```

Tambien es mala practica concadenar `String`, sobre todo porque ya estabas usando `StringBuilder`, puedes perfectamente realizarlo en varias sentencias para tu condicional:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
            .append("<p><b>Fecha:</b>").append(fecha.getText()).append("</p>")
            .append("<p><b>Obra:</b>").append(obra.getText()).append("</p>")
            .append("<p><b>Ancho:</b>").append(ancho2.getText()).append("</p>")
            .append("<p><bold>Observacion:</bold>").append(obs2.getText()).append("</p>");
if(!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    builder.append("<p>Titulo del campo:").append(editText.getText()).append("</p>");
}
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
        Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));
```